# Data Lake vs Raw Data Storage

Tags: memory, data-storage, data-management, data-lake

I'm new to Data Management and I have a somewhat confusing understanding of a "Data Lake". So by definition, it stores all types of data (structured and unstructured). However, if I just buy a server and set it up just to receive data and store it, does that also count as "building a Data Lake"?

Is the difference in the indexing and clever storage of data? i.e., easier to retrieve, able to trace data input/output. Or is there more to it than that?